# NSDate ignore timezone

Tags: swift, nsdate

How can you ignore the timezone altogether with NSDate?

Say I set the date of an important event to be `2016-03-11T23:00:00.701-05:00`

All I want is to return 2016-03-11 23:00 regardless of where you are or what timezone you are in. Basically if I say that event is going to happen on a particular date, I don't want it to change at all on anyone's phone/device.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
if let parsedDate = formatter.dateFromString(rawDate) {
   return parsedDate
}
```

Currently if I set it to a timezone that is +4 hrs, the event date displayed is incorrect. If its -4 hrs then the time portion is wrong.

Apart from the obvious as just setting the event date as a String, I wanted to keep it as an actual Date so the sorting would be easier (ascending/descending).

Any ideas on how to correctly format and ignoring timezones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store all your dates as UTC and display them in the timezone of the user who is viewing them, this is what makes most sense to you as the coder and the person as the user.

If you must do exactly what you explain then you need to set the locale when formatting your date such that the timezone isn't changed. This [Apple tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) explains how you process the date with and without timezone consideration.

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `NSDate` is not what you want here - because disregarding time zones makes its instances completely meaningless.

It's like saying "this car costs 100". Or - maybe more appropriate - "this car moved 100 meters. Where is it?"

So if you are just using a year, month, day, hour and minute, this may look like an `NSDate`, but it is not. It totally lacks context - and by using it the code is lying about what it is and does.